# Fix Shell PHP with cygwin error

Tags: php, bash, shell, cygwin

I am a new developer on Windows 7. I tried to install Babun to get my shell to be similar to zsh on mac OS, but I changed my mind and uninstalled it. However, now I'm unable to run my `php` commands and it still thinks I'm using `cygwin`. How can I change my bash settings back to normal?

```
$ php vendor/bin/propel

dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../propel/propel/bin" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
    # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
    # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
    # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
    if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
        dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
    fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/propel" "$@"
```

### EDIT

upon the command `echo $SHELL` I get `/usr/bin/bash`.

upon the command `cat ~/.bashrc` I get `alias subl="/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe".`

Nothing looks out of place ...

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` gives you?   then cat `~/.<your_shell>rc` for us to help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated the question to reflect the results

Comment: Why should two cd statements in a row ever make sense?

Comment: That was a part of the output ... I only called the one line with php above it :/ it doesn't make sense to me either